I am trying to Forecast a trend for the next year, using a historical data of past year (every 10 minute interval for 1 year) using SARIMAX
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax import SARIMAX
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import warnings
import numpy as np


import statsmodels.api as sm

try:
    print("Starting script...")

    # Load your dataset
    print("Loading dataset...")
    df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/iameh/Downloads/archive/powerconsumption.csv')

    # Convert 'Datetime' to datetime and set it as the index
    print("Preprocessing data...")
    df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])
    df.set_index('Datetime', inplace=True)

    # Define the p, d, q parameters to take any value between 0 and 1
    p = d = q = range(0, 2)

    # Generate all different combinations of p, q and q triplets
    pdq = list(itertools.product(p, d, q))

    # Generate all different combinations of seasonal p, q and q triplets
    seasonal_pdq = [(x[0], x[1], x[2], 12) for x in list(itertools.product(p, d, q))]

    # Specify to ignore warning messages
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

    # List of parameters to forecast
    parameters = ['Temperature', 'Humidity', 'WindSpeed', 'GeneralDiffuseFlows', 'DiffuseFlows', 'PowerConsumption_Zone1', 'PowerConsumption_Zone2', 'PowerConsumption_Zone3']

    print("Starting forecasting for each parameter...")
    for parameter in parameters:
        print(f"Forecasting for {parameter}...")
        
        # Select the relevant column for forecasting
        endog = df[parameter]

        # Find the best parameters for the model
        best_aic = np.inf
        best_pdq = None
        best_seasonal_pdq = None
        temp_model = None

        print("Finding best model parameters...")
        for param in pdq:
            for param_seasonal in seasonal_pdq:

                try:
                    temp_model = SARIMAX(endog,
                                         order = param,
                                         seasonal_order = param_seasonal,
                                         enforce_stationarity=False,
                                         enforce_invertibility=False)
                    results = temp_model.fit()

                    # print("SARIMAX{}x{}12 - AIC:{}".format(param, param_seasonal, results.aic))
                    if results.aic < best_aic:
                        best_aic = results.aic
                        best_pdq = param
                        best_seasonal_pdq = param_seasonal
                except:
                    continue

        print("Best SARIMAX{}x{}12 model for {} - AIC:{}".format(best_pdq, best_seasonal_pdq, parameter, best_aic))

        # Fit the best model
        print("Fitting the best model...")
        model = SARIMAX(endog,
                        order=best_pdq,
                        seasonal_order=best_seasonal_pdq,
                        enforce_stationarity=False,
                        enforce_invertibility=False)

        results = model.fit()

        # Get forecast steps ahead in future
        print("Making forecasts...")
        pred_uc = results.get_forecast(steps=52416)

        # Write the DataFrame to a CSV file
        print("Saving forecasts to CSV file...")
        pred_uc.predicted_mean.to_csv(f'C:/Users/iameh/Downloads/archive/{parameter}_forecast.csv')

        print(f"Forecasting for {parameter} completed!")

    print("Script completed!")

except Exception as e:
    print("An error occurred during the execution of the script:")
    print(e)

I am using this code to generate the next years prediction. But it is crashing/shell is restarting

Why is it crashing?

I dont know, its just restarting the shell. And the program is not running
